# How can I add columns from 2 different files to an output in CSV python

Tags: python, csv

my test.csv

```
1,1,2
2,1,3
3,1,4
```

my test2.csv

```
2,3
2,3
2,3
```

How can i make the output.csv:

```
1,1,2,2,3
2,1,3,2,3
3,1,4,2,3
```

so to combine two csv files to one?

Here's my code

```
import csv, os, sys
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as output, open ('test2.csv', 'rb') as input2:
        reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ',')
        reader2 = csv.reader(input2, delimiter = ',')
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',')

        all = []                                        
        header = next(reader)
        all.append(header)
        count = 0
        for row,row2 in reader and reader2:
                count += 1
                while count:
                        all.append(row+row2)
                        break
        writer.writerows(all)
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but does anybody understand what I'm going for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over both readers at once:

```
reader1 = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ',')
reader2 = csv.reader(input2, delimiter = ',')

for row1, row2 in zip(reader1, reader2):
    writer.writerow(row1 + row2)
```

Or a shorter version:

```
writer.writerows(map(list.__add__, row1, row2))
```

In case the files are huge then using `map`, `zip` is not going to be a good idea in Python 2, as they will load all the rows from both files, better go for their iterator versions present in 
itertools module: [`itertools.imap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) and [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

`for row,row2 in reader and reader2:` is equivalent to iterating over just `reader2` because [`and` works](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) like this:

```
>>> 1 and 2 
2
>>> 2 and 3
3
>>> 0 and 2  # returned the first falsy value, but as an iterator is not a falsy value
0            # so it will return `reader2` in your case.
```

**Update:**

To update test2.csv in-place you can use the `fileinput` module, but with this you won't be able to use the csv module.

```
>>> import fileinput
>>> with open('test.csv') as f:
    for line in fileinput.input('test2.csv', inplace=True):
        print next(f).rstrip() + ',' + line,
...         
>>> !cat test2.csv
1,1,2,2,3
2,1,3,2,3
3,1,4,2,3
```

Using csv module you'll have to read all the lines from test2.csv in memory first and then write the new data into it.

```
with open('test.csv') as f1, open('test2.csv', 'r+') as f2:
                                   #open in r+ mode
   reader1 = csv.reader(f1)
   rows_f2 = list(csv.reader(f2)) #read all the rows
   f2.truncate(0)                 #truncate the file
   writer = csv.writer(f2)
   writer.writerows(map(list.__add__, reader1, rows_f2))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I was wondering if this would be possible with only input and output file. E.g. 2 columns from input file(test.csv) added(or appended) to output file(test2.csv) without creating a third file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just concatenate line by line with comma...

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as output, open ('test2.csv', 'rb') as input2:
    for row, row2 in zip(input, input2):
        output.write(row.rstrip('\n') + ',' + row2)
```